# c# class that requires action as variable

Tags: c#, methods, execute

I have a c# program and I want to make a methodthat looks something like this

```
 public xx(??? a)
 {
     a.execute();
 }
```

then I want to call:

xx(Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\Users\Programmer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Key Logger\Output\Log.txt"));

and then have it do that.  I have no idea if something like this is accomplish-able, I am rather new to c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
public xx(Action a)
{
  a();
}

xx(()=> Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\\Output\Log.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Action` type for a parameterless delegate:

```
public xx(Action a) {
  a();
}
```

There is nothing that would turn a method call into a delegate, the compiler would just expect the method to return a delegate. You can use a lambda expression to easily create a delegate:

```
xx(() => Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\Users\Programmer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Key Logger\Output\Log.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public xx(Action a) {
}

xx(() => Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\Users\Programmer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Key Logger\Output\Log.txt"));
```

More info: [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), [delegate tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)